# Owin does not contain a definition for "UseHangfire" and no extension method "UseHangfire"

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I'm trying to setup Hangfire in VS 2013, I've installed it thru Package Manager. However, when I added the app.UseHangfire (...) code as stated in http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html. I'm getting the following error:

```
'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseHangfire' and no extension method 'UseHangfire' accepting a first argument of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: it's definitely there.  You must have incorrectly added the project or something.

Comment: @Jonesy `.UseHangfire()` is an extension method, you must import the namespace it's located in to be able to use it. Simply having the DLL in your project isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you add the namespace?

```
using Hangfire;
```

Your `Startup` should look something like this:

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseHangfire(config =>
            {
                config.UseSqlServerStorage("Data Source=<connectionstring>; Initial Catalog=HangFire; Trusted_Connection=true;");
                config.UseServer();

                //config.UseAuthorizationFilters(new AuthorizationFilter
                //{
                //    // Users = "admin, superuser", // allow only specified users
                //    Roles = "admins" // allow only specified roles
                //});
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This was it! But now it's pointing to config.UseSqlServerStorage(...) line saying Error 2 'Hangfire.IBootstrapperConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServerStorage' and no extension method 'UseSqlServerStorage' accepting a first argument of type 'Hangfire.IBootstrapperConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add `using Hangfire.SqlServer`

Comment: does this dispose the server gracefully when the owin instance shuts down?

Comment: @Zoba: I've found situations where a recurring task will actually keep the server alive. It shouldn't happen and everything should dispose gracefully but it is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the HangFire.Core package to latest solved it for me. Seems OWIN is installing an older package as dependency

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 1.4 Config is obsolete, use GlobalConfiguration instead:

```
public partial class Startup {

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString, new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            });

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();

    ...

    }
```